# Cannot open SSIS package (.dtproj file) after reinstalling Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, visual-studio-2015

I have made an SSIS-package in Visual Studio 2015. A bit after, I had to reinstall VS because there was some trouble with an unrelated package. Now when I try to open the SSIS-package, I first get the following popup:

```
The 'ResourceManagerPackage' package did not load correctly.

The problem may have been caused by a configuration change or by the installation of another extension. You can get more information by examining the file 'C:\Users\xxx\Appdata\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ActivityLog.xml'.

Restarting Visual Studio could help resolve this issue.

Continue to show this error message?
```

The popup pops up even when I just start VS.

After I click ok, the project does not load. In Solution Explorer, it says 'incompatible', and when I hover over it it says 'The application is not installed'.

How do I fix this?

**edit** I have run a repair of VS, and added the SSDT manually, no improvement. I have also opened the ActivityLog as suggested in the popup and searched for errors. I found this:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Project, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. 

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.Designer, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

This might be it, but since I cannot even open the solution, I do not know how to fix it anyway.

Comment: most likely that dll are missing form C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies

Comment: Ok, I will dig in to that when I get to work, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The version of SQL Server is crucial here. The version of VS has been historically always one behind SQL Server e.g. SQL Server 2012 uses Visual Studio 2010 to edit SSIS packages.

See more at [Download SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt)

As of 2022, this remains the case.

Comment: Ok, will check on monday!

Comment: The latest SSDT Preview for Visual Studio 2015 corrupted my installation of Visual Studio 2015 enterprise just two weeks ago... Hellogoodnight, proceed with caution!!!

Comment: FYI, the SSIS designer is part of the Integration Services component, you can't just do a base install of SSDT.

Comment: From the download page "If you don't have Visual Studio installed on your machine, installing SSDT for Visual Studio 2015 will also install a minimal “Integrated Shell” version of Visual Studio 2015. This version of Visual Studio is free to install and use on as many machines as you wish. It gives you all the SQL Server project types, plus SQL Server Object Explorer and other SQL tools experiences." - Microsoft

Comment: @Crutt .. in other words; yes, you can.

Comment: I have done this for VS 2017, and it doesn't seem to have solved the problem. SS 2014 installed. Product Version 10.50.1600.1 in dtproj.

Answer (score 1):

Were you using a SQL Server Data Tools plugin for Visual Studio to work on your SSIS package? You may need to re-install any other components like that which would be necessary to modify .dtsx files.

Link for SQL Server Data Tools in Visual Studio 2015 add on:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt186501.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

I would also recommend that you either re-install Visual Studio or use the installer to run the "Repair" operation on your installation. I hope this helps you! Problems with Visual Studio are never good...

**EDIT:** *Visual Studio 2012 + SQL Server Data Tools 2012* may allow you to continue creating your SSIS package. You may have to start over, but it will at least work... I've never been able to get Visual Studio 2015 to work with SQL Server Data Tools.

**Link for you:** [Previous releases of SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT and SSDT-BI)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674919.aspx)

Comment: Yes I was, but that comes with the installation so I should not be missing it, right? What other dependencies are there?

Comment: I didn't think it was a feature of the default installation, unless you're using a premium or ultimate version of VS? Even then I don't know that it comes with it... Try this link for VS 2015 SSDT installation media: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt186501.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I am using VS 2015 Professional, and I know for sure it is included

Comment: I didn't think SSDT is a default feature of VS2015 pro... I have run into this same problem before using VS2015 Enterprise, and I have not had any success using Data Tools in VS 2015 at all... If you can get an install of Visual Studio 2012 and use SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2012 you may have better luck. That's the only way I've been able to build new SSIS/SSRS objects... I wish you luck :(. Link to installers for previous versions of SSDT: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674919.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In addition to **[Ricardo C's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37352672/4427457)**, I had to install some of the **SQL Server 2012 Developer Edition** features.  Since I was trying to get SSIS packages to work, I installed 3 features (not sure which one fixed it):

1. SQL Server Data Tools (most were already installed)
2. Client Tools Backwards Compatibility
3. Integration Services

For completeness, I already had "Management Tools - Basic" and "Complete" installed, along with "SQL Client Connectivity SDK".

Also, I have this working alongside VS 2022 and SQL Server 2022.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools - Manage Extensions - Install- All . And checked SQL Server Integration Server Project is Enable. Visual studio not responding some times result in disabling SSIS project plugin.